# A question about cohomology with local coefficient

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let's consider the next theorem.

**Theorem
[The cohomology Leray-Serre Spectral sequence]** Let $R$ be a
commutative ring with unit. Given a fibration $F\hookrightarrow E\overset{p}{%
\rightarrow }B$, where $B$ is path-connected, there is a first quadrant
spectral sequence of algebras $\left\{ E_{r}^{\ast ,\ast },d_{r}\right\} $,
with
\begin{equation*}
E_{2}^{p,q}\cong H^{p}\left( B;\mathcal{H}^{q}\left( F;R\right) \right) 
\end{equation*}
and converging to $H^{\ast }\left( E;R\right) $ as an algebra, where $%
\mathcal{H}^{q}\left( F;R\right) $ denotes the cohomology of $B$ with local
coefficients in the cohomology of $F$, the fiber of $p$. Furthermore, this
spectral sequence is natural with respect to fiber-preserving maps of
fibrations.
I want to calculate \begin{equation*}
E_{2}^{p,0}\cong H^{p}\left( B;\mathcal{H}^{0}\left( F;R\right) \right) 
\end{equation*}
Some sources claim that if $F$ is path-connected, then the local coefficients system $\mathcal{H}%
^{0}\left( F;R
\right) $ over $B$ (here $R$ is a principal ideal domain, I don't know if the question has anything to do with this) is trivial and
\begin{equation*}
E_{2}^{p,0}=H^{p}\left( B;\mathcal{H}^{0}\left( F;R
\right) \right) =H^{p}\left( B;H^{0}\left( F;R
\right) \right) =H^{p}\left( B;R
\right)
\end{equation*}
First of all, I'm curious about the proof of this, that is why the local coefficients system $\mathcal{H}
^{0}\left( F;R
\right) $ over $B$ is trivial.

Secondly, is the path connectedness of $F$ related to the cohomology used?

I know that in the case of singular cohomology, $H^{0}\left( X;R\right) =R$ if
and only if $X$ is path-connected, and in the case of
Alexander-Spanier cohomology, $H^{0}\left( X;R\right) =R$ if and only if $X$
is connected.

So, If I use the Alexander-Spanier cohomology instead of the singular cohomology, is it enough for $F$ to be connected?

Comment: You can think of $H^0(F;R)$ as functions $\pi_0(F)\to R$, and $\pi_1(B)$ acts by pre-composing with the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $\pi_0(F)$. If $F$ is path-connected this action is clearly trivial.

Comment: I don't know about Alexander-Spanier cohomology, but presumably replace $\pi_0(F)$ with the set of connected components in the above comment.

Comment: @MarkGrant Can you write more clearly this action?

Comment: It is induced by the standard action map $\Omega B\times F\to F$ which comes from the homotopy lifting property, as described in many textbooks e.g. Hatcher's Algebraic Topology,  Chapter 4.

Comment: @MarkGrant The local coefficients system is given by $\pi_1 (B) \rightarrow Aut (H^0(F))$. So It seems to me that path connectedness of $F$ is related to the cohomology used. Am I wrong?

Comment: You are right. Most treatments of spectral sequences and local coefficients I've seen use singular or cellular cohomology, and/or restrict to nice spaces (so that path connected and connected coincide).

Comment: @MarkGrant if the space $F$ is not nice, but $H^0(F;\mathbb {Q})=\mathbb{Q}$, then still, is the system of local coefficients simple?, that is the homomorphism $\pi_1(F) \rightarrow Aut(H^0(F;\mathbb{Q}))$ is trivial?

Comment: I see what you're asking. If $H^0(F;\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Q}$ then $F$ is path-connected, and since the action of $\pi_1(B)$ on $H^0(F;\mathbb{Q})$ is induced by a permutation of path components, this action is trivial.

Comment: @MarkGrant No, $H^0(F;\mathbb{Q})=\mathbb{Q}$, but $F$ is not path-connected, just connected, then is it trivial?

Comment: You'd just need to check if the 0th Alexander-Spanier cohomology is functions on the connected components.